# Error when insert document (format: json) in Apache Solr using Python

Tags: python, json, solr

I am beginner to Apache Solr. I want to add documents into Apache Solr. And after that I want to extract the information from Apache Solr.

For e.g. I have CV(Curriculum Vitae) documents in JSON format. So I want to extract the information like 'NAME', 'EMAIL-ID', 'EXPERIENCE', 'SKILLS' etc.

The way I have tried :

I am trying to add documents in Apache Solr using Python. But when I add document that time I get an error.

My code is following:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pysolr
solr = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/try', timeout=10)

#https://tecadmin.net/install-apache-solr-on-ubuntu/
solr.add(
    {
    "content": "Afreen Jamadar\nActive member of IIIT Committee in Third year\n\nSangli, Maharashtra - Email me on Indeed: indeed.com/r/Afreen-Jamadar/8baf379b705e37c6\n\nI wish to use my knowledge, skills and conceptual understanding to create excellent team\nenvironments and work consistently achieving organization objectives believes in taking initiative\nand work to excellence in my work.\n\nWORK EXPERIENCE\n\nActive member of IIIT Committee in Third year\n\nCisco Networking -  Kanpur, Uttar Pradesh\n\norganized by Techkriti IIT Kanpur and Azure Skynet.\nPERSONALLITY TRAITS:\n• Quick learning ability\n• hard working\n\nEDUCATION\n\nPG-DAC\n\nCDAC ACTS\n\n2017\n\nBachelor of Engg in Information Technology\n\nShivaji University Kolhapur -  Kolhapur, Maharashtra\n\n2016\n\nSKILLS\n\nDatabase (Less than 1 year), HTML (Less than 1 year), Linux. (Less than 1 year), MICROSOFT\nACCESS (Less than 1 year), MICROSOFT WINDOWS (Less than 1 year)\n\nADDITIONAL INFORMATION\n\nTECHNICAL SKILLS:\n\n• Programming Languages: C, C++, Java, .net, php.\n• Web Designing: HTML, XML\n• Operating Systems: Windows […] Windows Server 2003, Linux.\n• Database: MS Access, MS SQL Server 2008, Oracle 10g, MySql.\n\nhttps://www.indeed.com/r/Afreen-Jamadar/8baf379b705e37c6?isid=rex-download&ikw=download-top&co=IN",
    "annotation": [{
        "label": ["Email Address"],
        "points": [{
            "start": 1155,
            "end": 1198,
            "text": "indeed.com/r/Afreen-Jamadar/8baf379b705e37c6"
        }]
    }, {
        "label": ["Links"],
        "points": [{
            "start": 1143,
            "end": 1239,
            "text": "https://www.indeed.com/r/Afreen-Jamadar/8baf379b705e37c6?isid=rex-download&ikw=download-top&co=IN"
        }]
    }, {
        "label": ["Skills"],
        "points": [{
            "start": 743,
            "end": 1140,
            "text": "Database (Less than 1 year), HTML (Less than 1 year), Linux. (Less than 1 year), MICROSOFT\nACCESS (Less than 1 year), MICROSOFT WINDOWS (Less than 1 year)\n\nADDITIONAL INFORMATION\n\nTECHNICAL SKILLS:\n\n• Programming Languages: C, C++, Java, .net, php.\n• Web Designing: HTML, XML\n• Operating Systems: Windows […] Windows Server 2003, Linux.\n• Database: MS Access, MS SQL Server 2008, Oracle 10g, MySql."
        }]
    }, {
        "label": ["Graduation Year"],
        "points": [{
            "start": 729,
            "end": 732,
            "text": "2016"
        }]
    }, {
        "label": ["College Name"],
        "points": [{
            "start": 675,
            "end": 702,
            "text": "Shivaji University Kolhapur "
        }]
    }, {
        "label": ["Degree"],
        "points": [{
            "start": 631,
            "end": 672,
            "text": "Bachelor of Engg in Information Technology"
        }]
    }, {
        "label": ["Graduation Year"],
        "points": [{
            "start": 625,
            "end": 629,
            "text": "2017\n"
        }]
    }, {
        "label": ["College Name"],
        "points": [{
            "start": 614,
            "end": 622,
            "text": "CDAC ACTS"
        }]
    }, {
        "label": ["Degree"],
        "points": [{
            "start": 606,
            "end": 611,
            "text": "PG-DAC"
        }]
    }, {
        "label": ["Companies worked at"],
        "points": [{
            "start": 438,
            "end": 453,
            "text": "Cisco Networking"
        }]
    }, {
        "label": ["Email Address"],
        "points": [{
            "start": 104,
            "end": 147,
            "text": "indeed.com/r/Afreen-Jamadar/8baf379b705e37c6"
        }]
    }, {
        "label": ["Location"],
        "points": [{
            "start": 62,
            "end": 67,
            "text": "Sangli"
        }]
    }, {
        "label": ["Name"],
        "points": [{
            "start": 0,
            "end": 13,
            "text": "Afreen Jamadar"
        }]
    }],
    "extras": None,
    "metadata": {
        "first_done_at": 1527844872000,
        "last_updated_at": 1537724086000,
        "sec_taken": 0,
        "last_updated_by": "BIQNZm4INNfvByMqkaVwVt6OZTv2",
        "status": "done",
        "evaluation": "CORRECT"
    }
})
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 96, in <module>
NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

**When I modified "extras" : None, Then below error I got.**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 103, in <module>
  File "/home/system/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 907, in add
    el = self._build_doc(doc, boost=boost, fieldUpdates=fieldUpdates)
  File "/home/system/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 822, in _build_doc
    for key, value in doc.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Please help me to solve this error. You help will be appreciated.

Comment: `null` while part of the json spec is not valid in Python. Change it to `None`. When it gets serialized as json, it will get converted to null.

Comment: In your json data change "extras": null to "extras":None

Comment: Please see I again got error. I have updated it. @jordanm, pushpendra chauhan

Comment: Please reply @jordanm

Comment: Please reply @pushpendrachauhan

Comment: its still showing null only @Heena

Comment: I have updated it now. Please check @pushpendrachauhan

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem.

solr = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/try', timeout=10)

I have not specified solr.

solr = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/try', timeout=10)